# Output of a small array sort algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am working on a small array sort algorithm and i just dont get why my output looks similar to this:

> [I@4e5a5622

when this is not close to what i expected...

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    int[] array = {5,45,234,3};
    int n = array.length;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        int m = n-1;
        for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++){
            if(array[j]<array[m]){
                m=j;
            }
        }
    int t= array[i]; array[i] = array[m]; array[m] = t;
    }
    System.out.println(array.toString());
}
```

Thanks for helping :D

Comment: What you're seeing is the hash of the object array. You can loop over the array and print each array element independently to see the actual value.

Comment: @RoelStrolenberg Nah. Read the API documentation ;)

Answer (score 0):

try to use the `Arrays.toString()`

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```